# How can I make this table in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, tidyverse

How can I make a table like this :

[image]

In this table, `Col_1` and `Col_2` are independent variables, while `Col_3` is dependent variable ( `Col_1 + Col_2 = Col_3` )

Can anyone help me?

Comment: have you tried rowSums() ?

Comment: Gambit - please test the code I provide in my answer and comment if it fails or accept if it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have data in a data.frame called df

```
df$Col_3 <- df$Col_1 + df$Col_2
```

Where

```
df <- data.frame("Col_1" = c(2,4,5,7,6), "Col_2" = c(3,7,4,8,4))
```

The original data.frame is made using the `data.frame()` function, passing two double-type (numeric) vectors, created with the `c()` function. The two columns are isolated as vectors using `$`, summed using arithmetic operator `+` and assigned to a new column in df using the assign operator `<-`.

Other ways of doing this would include the `rowSums()` function, `mutate()` in the tidyverse packages (`df %>% mutate(Col_3 = Col_1 + Col_2) -> df`) or using a data.table (see the data.table package: `dt[, Col_3 := Col_1 + Col_2]` which would be my go to).

Comment: This is a very basic question and you really should have found an answer in previous posts. However, that is tricky because there's a lot of material and the search feature is only really helpful if you know what you are looking for, so I've provided an answer and tried to give a detailed explanation of the process. Remember to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: hi, I am sorry that I am a little bit slow because I am new to r. It solves my problems and I learnt a lot from you ! But can I ask you another question? Do you know how to apply the table like this in shiny in r? Which is to create an user interface..

Comment: is it the same concept to apply this in shiny?

Comment: In principle yes absolutely, but I've hardly used shiny so can't guarantee it...

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using data.table, as it would be as easy as

```
DT[,"Col_3":=Col_2+Col_3]
```

Sorry, I do not have enough rep to comment

Comment: is okay, I am still very appreciate that you commented it! Thank!

Answer (score 2):

A tidyverse solution would be

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(Col_3 = Col_1 + Col_2)
```

Where `df` is

```
df <- data.frame("Col_1" = c(2,4,5,7,6), "Col_2" = c(3,7,4,8,4))
```

Comment: @OP: for more complex cases, see the renewed `rowwise()` function in `dplyr 1.0.0` https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-rowwise/